# Matching records using Exists - Dbeaver

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, exists, dbeaver

I have a very long query. But i want to find if i have the certain cust_nbr in the query or not. It should just say True or False. Only putting in the last CTE to figure this out. But this doesn't looks like its working.

For example: If '015100' is in the records from 'sales_fw_co_cust' Then it should say as a third column True or else False.

```
select co_nbr, cust_nbr,
        case when exists 
            (
                select distinct  co_nbr, cust_nbr
                from sales_fw_co_cust
                where cust_nbr in ('015100','015105','015435','015589', '020085',   '020184')
            )
            then 'True'
            else 'False'
            end as EXIST_NOT
            from sales_fw_co_cust
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the query"? Is this what you're looking for: `select co_nbr, cust_nbr, case when cust_nbr in ('015100','etc') then 'True' else 'False' end from sales_fw_co_cust`.

Comment: I don't think you need *exists* here (your usage indicates you don't fully understand it) just a case expression in your main select clause.